# Can a Windows CE netbook run Windows XP?

Tags: windows, compatibility, windows-ce

Can you upgrade a nebook running Windows CE to Windows XP?

Can you download music?

I just bought two for my grandkids ages 12 and 14.

Comment: Please post the specs, processor ghz, drive space, and amount of installed memory, or post the Make and model you purchased.

Answer (score 2):

**Short**: No.

**Long**: CE and XP are two entirely different things. CE is an embedded thing used for (old) portable devices. XP is a "real" OS.

**My Advice**: Netbooks are only $400 for a decent one. Shop around Amazon and get ones that are relatively recent. Or get iPads ^-^.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what a netbook ce is, but I assume it is running [Windows CE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_ce).  If that is the case then, no it cannot be upgraded to Windows XP, nor any other version of Windows.  Windows CE is not a standard version of Windows that you find on desktops or laptops.  Windows CE was originally built for smart phones and runs on different hardware than regular Windows.

It also cannot run programs that on Windows XP, etc.  Windows CE can only run programs that were specifically designed for it - which rules out all normal Windows programs.

You most likely can download music on it, it probably has some version of Windows Media Player and can download files.  But it won't be able to run iTunes, Winamp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading cant be done, however it *is* possible to replace Windows CE with another operating system.  There are many cases on Windows CE being replaced with Linux and Windows XP.  You need to be able to access and modify the flash storage.  Also, obtaining compatible device drivers can be an issue.  This is not an easy task to accomplish and I would not recommend trying it unless you are an advanced computer user, as it is possible to permanently break the netbook.